# Spawning go routines in a loop with closure

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have a list of strings which can contain number of elements ranging from 1 to 100,000. I want to verify each string and see if they are stored in a database, which requires call to network.

In order to maximize the efficiency, I want to spawn a go routine for each element.
Goal is to return `false` if one of the verifications inside the go routine function returns `err`, and return `true` if there is no `err`. So if we find at least one `err` we can stop since we already know that it is going to return `false`.

This is the basic idea, and the function below is the structure I've been thinking about using so far. I'd like to know if there is a better way (perhaps using channel?).

```
for _, id := range userIdList {
    go func(id string){
        user, err := verifyId(id)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // ...
        // few more calls to other APIs for verifications
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }(id)
}
```

Comment: You will need a channel, or something like it, to communicate results from your `go` threads back to the main program. As it stands, all the errors you're returning are ignored, and the main thread will continue on with its business no matter what any of these goroutines do.

Comment: In fact, it won't compile as-is, because you're returning a value from a function with no return values in its signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrote a small function that might be helpful for you. 
Please take a look at [limited parallel operations](https://play.golang.org/p/P3hb7FzJUD)